# assign names to values that are already in a data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to `assign()` or `<-` into the current environment, based on names and values in this data.frame.

```
df = tibble::tribble(~x, ~value,
                "var1", "val1",
                "var2", "val2")
```

Both `assign()` and `<-` have named formal arguments `x`, `value`. Why does the following not achieve this simple task and what, equally concise, alternatives are available?

```
purrr::pwalk(df, assign)
```

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to specify the environment, otherwise objects are assigned to the current environment.  It's bad practice to clutter the global environment but you may be looking for `purrr::pwalk(df, assign, envir = .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks for the help. I now use envir = rlang::current_env().